# How to add a custom button with icon AND text?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

In the header. It looks that whenever I set a icon, the text does not appear. Looks like is just one or the other.
Is it possible to have both? I could not find how.

Comment: I would not say this title says anything - - - WHERE do you want the custom button? WHAT should it do?  What sort of Icon (not that it matters much, but some detail might help....)?  Show some effort on what you tried - or at least what you are really wanting to do!

Comment: @CFPSupport I assume OP means this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons

Comment: Sadly I don't think this is possible using the customButtons option as currently implemented. Perhaps you can make a feature request to the fullCalendar maintainers (if one does not exist already): https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features